# Mumble/Google protobufs client side read data function error

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, protocol-buffers

I am trying to develop a mumble client. To connect to a mumble server (also called murmur) I need to follow steps listed in wiki "https://mumble-protocol.readthedocs.org/en/latest/establishing_connection.html#connect".

I am coding in Windows Visual Studios in C++.

Step 1 is to establish a TCP connection to server and do a TSLv1 handshake.

I tried to establish a TCP connection and successfully did a TSL handshake. Then I tried to read data using SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)), the function returns 55 (which is number of bytes it read). However, the buffer is still empty when I try to log it out to console.

I log it out in 3 ways:

1. printf() - since buf is declared as char array, I print it out as using %s in printf()
2. cout - print out raw buffer using std::cout
3. I was aware the murmur might send binary data back to me, so I tried to force cast the first 4 bytes into a uint32_t and tried to see if I am even getting an data back. It printed 0, meaning the data was just nothing.

I know that my client is reading some data because of 3 reasons:

1. SSL_read returns number of data read which is 55 in this case.
2. I tried to connect to google IP at port 433. The program kept running after the connection was done. It never finished running and it SSL_read didn't return any data. (google doesn't send data like that, so this makes sense)
3. Mumble Wiki says after successful connection, the server should send its version information.

**My question is that why can't I see the data that is being read. Is there anything that I am missing in connecting to SSL or is there something wrong with the way I am reading from server.**

**For those who has made a mumble client: How to get version information from the murmur server ?**

Here is my code. [Check my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNYck.png)

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib")
/*****************************************************************************/
/*** ssl_client.c                                                          ***/
/***                                                                       ***/
/*** Demonstrate an SSL client.                                            ***/
/*****************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>

//#include <sys/socket.h>
//#include <resolv.h>
//#include <netdb.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define FAIL    -1

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*--- OpenConnection - create socket and connect to server.         ---*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
SOCKET OpenConnection(const char *hostname, int port)
{
    SOCKET sd;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    WSADATA wsadata;

    int error = WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsadata);

    //Did something happen?
    if (error)
        return false;

    //Did we get the right Winsock version?
    if (wsadata.wVersion != 0x0202)
    {
        WSACleanup(); //Clean up Winsock
        return false;
    }


    printf("Starting connection\n");
    /*
    if ((host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("No Host\n");
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }*/

    //memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostname);

    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    int err = connect(sd, (SOCKADDR *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    printf("Socket: %d\n", sd);
    if (err!= 0)
    {
        closesocket(sd);
        perror(hostname);
    }
    else 
        printf("Connected to %s:%d\n", hostname, port);
        return sd;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*--- InitCTX - initialize the SSL engine.                          ---*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)
{
    const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    SSL_library_init(); /* load encryption & hash algorithms for SSL */
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();       /* Load cryptos, et.al. */      /* Bring in and register error messages */
    method = TLSv1_client_method();     /* Create new client-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);          /* Create new context */
    if (ctx == NULL)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    return ctx;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*--- ShowCerts - print out the certificates.                       ---*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{
    X509 *cert;
    char *line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);   /* get the server's certificate */
    if (cert != NULL)
    {
        printf("Server certificates:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("\t Subject: %s\n", line);
        OPENSSL_free(line);                         /* free the malloc'ed string */
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("\t Issuer: %s\n", line);
        OPENSSL_free(line);                         /* free the malloc'ed string */
        X509_free(cert);                    /* free the malloc'ed certificate copy */
    }
    else
        printf("No certificates.\n");
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*--- main - create SSL context and connect                         ---*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main()
{
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    SOCKET server;
    SSL *ssl;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes;
    char *hostname;
    hostname = <put host name here>;
    int portnum = <put port here>;

    ctx = InitCTX();
    printf("Initialised SSL\n");
    server = OpenConnection(hostname, portnum);
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);                     /* create new SSL connection state */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);                /* attach the socket descriptor */
    if (SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL)           /* perform the connection */
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    else
    {
        int handshake = SSL_do_handshake(ssl);
        printf("Handshake Status: %i\n", handshake);

        char *msg = "Hello???";
        printf("Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
        ShowCerts(ssl);/* get any certs */

        const char* state = SSL_state_string(ssl);
        printf("State: %s\n", state);

        //SSL_write(ssl, msg, strlen(msg));         /* encrypt & send message */
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));    /* get reply & decrypt */
        buf[bytes] = '\0';
        printf("Received %d bytes: \"%s\"\n", bytes,buf);

        std::cout <<"Raw Buffer: " << buf[2] << "\n";

        uint32_t *test = (uint32_t *)buf;
        printf("Buffer force casted to 32 bit int: %u\n", *test);

        SSL_free(ssl);                              /* release connection state */
    }
    closesocket(server);                                    /* close socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);                              /* release context */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to read the first (Version) message, which you didn't state, and assuming that 'common string' means 'null-terminated string', and assuming you read a complete message into `buf` in the first place:

```
printf("Version %04x release %s OS %s OS version %s\n",
    *(int*)buf,
    buf+4,
    buf+4+strlen(buf+4)+1,
    buf+4+strlen(buf+4+strlen(buf+4)+1)+1
    );
```

... or similar. Note that the version info is in hex not decimal.

E&OE

Comment: It worked. Thanks :) 
It does not exactly solve my problem of reading data. But through your code I was able to figure out what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

Through [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp) answer, I was able to find a solution to my problem. Basically, Mumble uses google protocol buffer to send and receive data. Google protocol buffers sends 6 bytes of information regarding the data before actually sending the data itself. Those 6 bytes in my case were '/0' for some reason. So the reason my force cast didn't work was that there was nothing read in those 6 bytes.

However, when I printed the buffer using [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp)'s, code

```
printf("Version %04x release %s OS %s OS version %s\n",
*(int*)buf,
buf+4,
buf+4+strlen(buf+4)+1,
buf+4+strlen(buf+4+strlen(buf+4)+1)+1
);
```

I was able to see the data after those 6 bytes. The correct way to process data is not by neglecting the first 6 bytes, but to implement google protocol buffers to interpret those 6 bytes and the data sent by protocol buffers. This way you can get data in any language you want(that is what protocol buffer does).

To get more info visit [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).

If you are creating a mumble client in C++ ,you might also want to visit [Mumlib Library](https://github.com/slomkowski/mumlib).